# Cannot connect to Mongo Atlas from app deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

My project is connecting perfectly to mongoAtlas when run locally, but it does not connect to mongoAtlas when deployed on heroku. I have set all the environment variables on heroku. I have also set whitelist IP on mongo Atlas to 0.0.0.0/0 so it can be accessed from anywhere. But the problem still exists.

> app.js

```
var express  = require("express");
var app      = express();
var mongoose =require("mongoose");
var passport =require("passport");
var localStrategy = require("passport-local");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var methodOverride =require("method-override");
var flash =require("connect-flash");

var Comment=require("./models/comment");
var Post = require("./models/post");
var User = require("./models/user");

var postRoutes = require("./routes/posts");
var profileRoutes = require("./routes/profile");
var authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
var indexRoutes = require("./routes/index");
var commentRoutes = require("./routes/comments");

require('dotenv').config()
app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.locals.moment = require('moment');

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(flash());

//for jquery
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;
var $ = require("jquery")(window);

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: 'ghostx61', 
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, 
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

//DATABASEURL variable for mongoAtlas
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL || "mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoDemo_v7");


//passport config
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "dsadsfjfgjhfghfdjhfgjgdhjkg",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.message= req.flash("error");
    next();
});

app.use(profileRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(postRoutes);
app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use(commentRoutes);

//IP variable for heroku deploy
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

> ERROR shown when heroku logs --tail command is executed

```
2019-08-08T16:37:25.986574+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-08-08T16:37:28.077231+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2019-08-08T16:37:28.077269+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2019-08-08T16:37:28.077271+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2019-08-08T16:37:28.084568+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version.
To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
2019-08-08T16:37:28.085200+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running on port 3000
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254212+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-bd7rs.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-01-bd7rs.mongodb.net:27017 closed]
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254215+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254217+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254219+00:00 app[web.1]: at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254221+00:00 app[web.1]: at callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:109:5)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254222+00:00 app[web.1]: at runCommand (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:129:7)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254224+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.errorHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:321:5)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254226+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254227+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254229+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:350:12)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254231+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254233+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254234+00:00 app[web.1]: at _handle.close (net.js:606:12)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254237+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:388:7)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254299+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
2019-08-08T16:37:28.254365+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

I added error handling to mongoose.connect()  method and it worked.Note that this code only handles initial connection errors which was the problem in the first place .To know more about it, visit [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling)

> code
>
> ```
> mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL || "mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoDemo_v7", { useNewUrlParser: true }).
>   catch(error => handleError(error));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To allow access for heroku app you will need to turn on `allow access from anywhere`. Refer here for steps [MongoDB IP Whitelist](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/)

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information in the link provided in the answer itself. This can stop your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.

Comment: Opening the whitelist to the entire internet is not a great solution.